# How to use AES-CBC 128-bit encryption in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, encryption, aes

I would like to encrypt a string in AS3 with `AES-CBC 128-bit`. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use AS3Crypto https://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/, here is the snippet:

```
//notice that decrKey and decrIV length must be 16 chars long! ex: 1234567890123456
private function encrypt(input:String,decrKey:String,decrIV:String):String
{
    var inputBA:ByteArray=Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(input));        
    var key:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(decrKey));                
    var pad:IPad = new NullPad();
    var aes:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher("aes-cbc", key, pad);
    var ivmode:IVMode = aes as IVMode;
    ivmode.IV = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(decrIV));            
    aes.encrypt(inputBA);  

    return Base64.encodeByteArray( inputBA);  //if not use Base64 encode, data would be just byteArray
}
```

Notice: this code is fully compatible ex: with PHP (or C#), here is decryption for it in PHP

```
//notice that $key and $iv length must be 16 chars long! ex: 1234567890123456
function decrypt($data,$key,$iv)
{

    $decr= mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);    
    return $decr;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples. Does the `decrKey and decrIV` need to be numbers only?

Comment: They can be any symbols, they are converted into byteArray anyway.

Comment: I just though it may be safer to encrypt the string directky in PHP. Is this the right way to do it?: `function encrypt($data,$key,$iv)
{
$decr= mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_encode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);    
    return $decr;   
}    ` Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes syntax is very similar, you can use it in that way.

Comment: any sample for the same thing for c++ ?

Comment: @igrek Sorry, C++ isn't my strong side, IMHO you can use https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1380/A-C-Implementation-of-the-Rijndael-Encryption-Decr and this also would give directions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292727/can-i-decrypt-data-in-c-encrypted-via-php